# WLST: Custom roles and grups to deployed application

Tags: jython, weblogic12c, wlst

I'm deploying an ear to one of my Weblogic servers with CustomRoles security model. From the console it's not a problem to define a new role and to assign it to a group.

However I'm trying to do this from the WLST console with no success. Is there a way to do this with WLST? The deployment/undeployment gives me no problem using the following commands

```
deploy('app','app.ear','server', securityModel='CustomRoles')
undeploy('app','server')
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/config_wls.htm#WLSTG206)

You want to do something like

```
serverConfig()
 auth=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupAuthenticationProvider("DefaultAuthenticator")
auth.createUser(login, password, login)
auth.addMemberToGroup(group, login)
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked (which is creating a role and assigning to a group, not creating a user and assigning that to a group)